# how to change a color of widget based on condition flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an IconButton and I want to change the icon and color when the list of orders is not empty, I created two IconData , one for full cart , and one for empty cart.
At the first it was changing the color and the cart type , but now it doesn't change until I go back to first activity (page) then reopen this actitvity (page) again .. I don't what is the problem .
here is the code I used; Please need help

```
 IconData cartIcon= Icons.add_shopping_cart;
 IconData cart2 = Icons.shopping_cart;
   
IconButton(
   
          icon:widget.rest.items_to_Order.isEmpty?Icon(cartIcon, color: Colors.white,):Icon(cart2 , 
           color: Colors.amber,),
          iconSize: 30,
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> new list_orders_page(widget.rest)));
          },
        ),
```

Comment: Are you using any setState() methods to trigger the rebuild?

Comment: @VinoopKS no I did not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should rebuild the widget with `setState(() {});`
Here is an example of the itinerary operation:

```
color: booleanVariable == true ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
```

And when there is a 'onTap' action use `setState(() {booleanVariable = true;});` to change the color.

Bool variable is just an option, you can use different type of variables.